# Url rewrite not working for first segment of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is the rule I use in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domaina.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domainb.com/$1 [P]
```

For some reason this works perfectly for everything such as http://domaina.com/something-here but fails miserably only for requests to http://domaina.com

Can anyone shed some light as to why that is ?

Thank you.

**EDIT**
Problem solved, I had forgotten the `http://` part! However, this brought about a new problem: http://domaina.com/john doesn't work, but http://domaina.com/john/doe does...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `L` (last) flag:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domaina\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainb.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working. However, is there anything I should 'flush' like a dnscache or something?

Comment: `I had forgotten the http://` But your question originally showed `http://` also.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it was a matter of placement :

Other rewrite rules I had were on top of the new ones and therefore overriding what I was trying to create.